# Unexpected result for (unwords . words)

Tags: haskell

Can anyone explain the behavior of `unwords . words` in the example below. I would expect it to remove all the double spaces in the string `s`, however apparently it doesn't. On the other hand the behavior of `unwords (words s)` is as expected.

```
Prelude> s
"this     is   a  test    "
Prelude> unwords (words s) 
"this is a test"
Prelude> (unwords . words) s 
"this     is   a  test    "
Prelude> (unwords . words) s == unwords (words s)
False
Prelude> (unwords . words) s == s 
True
```

I use GHCi 8.2.2 on OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: Can't reproduce on ghci 8.0.2, windows.

Comment: @Zpalmtree i use os x, see my edit

Comment: Cannot reproduce with GHCi 8.2.1 on Windows.

Comment: The expressions `(f . g) x` and `f (g x)` are definitionally equal; it really isn't possible that they have different values (unless you've snuck in a use of an unsafe function somewhere, or your installation of GHC is somehow massively broken).

Comment: Ok, so it is likely to be a bug and I might report it. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: @Elmex80s Are you certain that you're copying and pasting the exact code that you are typing in?

Comment: @Elmex80s If you can reproduce your issue by running e.g. [this](https://repl.it/repls/OutgoingDimOryx) program, then it's likely a bug, but I would assume it isn't a bug in GHC. If that program doesn't show the issue, then it's a user error. Whether you delete the question is up to you (but if you do find out it's a bug, feel free to post a link to the bug report along with a short explanation as an answer).

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Linux or OS X with GHCi 8.0.1 and 8.2.1 respectively. I'm voting to close this question due to being unreproducible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suspect you probably wrote something like:

```
Prelude> (unwords . words) s = s   -- oops: used "=" instead of "=="
```

earlier in your GHCi session.  This would have the effect of redefining the `(.)` operator so that `f . g` is the identity function for any `f` and `g`, after which you'd get the observed behavior:

```
Prelude> unwords (words "a  b  c  ")
"a b c"
Prelude> (unwords . words) "a  b  c  "
"a  b  c  "
```

or even:

```
Prelude> (16 . map) "hello, world!"
"hello, world!"
```

Comment: **Yes there is no bug**. By typing `(unwords . words) s = s` I accidentally made `(unwords . words)` the identity function throughout the whole session of course regardless the values for `s`, as I redefined `s` several times during the session.

Comment: @Elmex80s: you did not *only* make `(unwords . words)` the identity function. Note that `unwords` and `words` are variables here. You make `(.) x y` the identity function. Regardless what the two operands are.

Comment: Wow, you have made a frankly amazing deductive leap here. Well done.